# Capturing an exit code for passing or failing Cucumber scenarios

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, rubymine, gherkin

I am writing Gherkin scenarios, I have an After hook I am currently working on. I want to be able to increment two variables (passing, failing) depending on the status of a scenario after it has been ran.

Does Cucumber return an exit code, and if it does, how do you capture it in code?

My tests are being written in RubyMine, and I am testing a web-application using Watir-Webdriver (just in case you need to know).

Comment: Look at the documentation for whatever you are using the run the cucumber tests within Ruby, there should be a way to retrieve an exit code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scenario.failed?` or `scenario.passed?` in your After hook to check for scenario status:

```
After do |scenario|
  # Do something after each scenario.
  # The +scenario+ argument is optional, but
  # if you use it, you can inspect status with
  # the #failed?, #passed? and #exception methods.

  if scenario.failed?
    subject = "[Project X] #{scenario.exception.message}"
    send_failure_email(subject)
  end
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks